# Convert Json string to Java object gives null (null)

Tags: java, json

Hello i got this Json string

```
{"NexusResource":{"resourceURI":"http://nexus.ad.hrm.se/nexus/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/se/hrmsoftware/hrm/hrm-release/16.1-SNAPSHOT/","relativePath":"/se/hrmsoftware/hrm/hrm-release/16.1-SNAPSHOT/","text":"16.1-SNAPSHOT","leaf":false,"lastModified":"2018-04-09 12:23:59.0 UTC","sizeOnDisk":-1}}
```

I want to convert this to an object of a class named NexusResource that looks like this

```
public class NexusResource {
@JsonProperty("resourceURI") private String resourceURI;
@JsonProperty("relativePath") private String relativePath;
@JsonProperty("text") private String text;
@JsonProperty("leaf") private Boolean leaf;
@JsonProperty("lastModified") private String lastModified;
@JsonProperty("sizeOnDisk") private Integer sizeOnDisk;
@JsonIgnore private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();
}
```

i try to convert it with an ObjectMapper

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    NexusResource resource = mapper.readValue(version, NexusResource.class);
```

were version is the Json string but when i log resource all i get is null (null) even though version got all the data.

Comment: may you provide us with you model class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your `ObjectMapper` to unwrap the root value, in order to de-serialize into your POJO.

E.g.:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

See [API](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE).

You could also work around that by modifying your POJO (see [Karol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1602555/karol-dowbecki)'s answer).

Failure to choose either should result in a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException` being thrown, with message: `Unrecognized field "NexusResource"`.

Answer (score 1):

`NexusResource` is not a root of your JSON but a key. To make your Java mapping work you should define a wrapping type:

```
public class NexusResources {
  @JsonProperty("NexusResource") private NexusResource root;
  ...
}
```

and then use it to map:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
NexusResources root = mapper.readValue(version, NexusResources.class);
NexusResource resource = root.getRoot();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the JSON does not match the class you are trying to parse.  Please notice that the JSON has a field called "NexusResource" that has all the other fields.  Whereas the class `NexusResource.class` just has the fields.  Two things you can do.  Change the JSON to match NexusResource.class, or create a new class that matches the JSON.

1)  Change the json to the following.

```
{"resourceURI":"http://nexus.ad.hrm.se/nexus/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/se/hrmsoftware/hrm/hrm-release/16.1-SNAPSHOT/","relativePath":"/se/hrmsoftware/hrm/hrm-release/16.1-SNAPSHOT/","text":"16.1-SNAPSHOT","leaf":false,"lastModified":"2018-04-09 12:23:59.0 UTC","sizeOnDisk":-1}
```

2)  Create new class that actually matches your Json.

```
class NexusResourceJson {

    @JsonProperty("NexusResource ")
    NexusResource resource;

    public NexusResource getResource() {return resource;}
}


ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
NexusResource resource = mapper.readValue(version, NexusResourceJson.class).getResource();
```